# Radio button problem using subtitles and mandatory field check

Tags: text, radio

I have a problem with a WordPress website using radio buttons.

At the moment, there are 6 radio buttons, divided in 3 groups: group of 3, group of 2 and group of 1.

The groups have been made like this, because each group required a subtitle in front (in our context, it's a separation between youth, adults and competition playing). Putting all radio buttons in the same group doesn't allow putting the subtitles between the radio buttons.

But having the 3 groups doesn't allow us to enforce a control at registration to check if one of the three groups has been selected, as one of the 6 radio buttons should be selected (as in mandatory).

Has anyone a workaround to either: enable mandatory field check for the 6 radio buttons separated in 3 groups or a solution to put all radio buttons in one group, so mandatory field check is a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about assigning different numbers to each of the radio buttons and have a minimum value when it returns? If it returns 0 or NULL then display a message? So youth group could be something like.

**YOUTH**

```
[checkbox] 5 - 8 (value 1)
[checkbox] 9 - 12 (value 2)
[checkbox] 12 - 16 (value 3)
```

etc you get the point.

That way if it returns 2 then you know it's the 9-12 group. You could store any of the checkbox group results to the same variable and check that.